# Django - how to run syncdb after 'south' is an installed app?

Tags: python, django, django-south, django-syncdb

I added south in my installed apps so that I can do schemamigrations. I then added

```
django.contrib.admin
```

and

```
django.contrib.flatpages
```

to the installed apps. Now, normally I would just do

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

but is that the correct way to do it after installing south? Here (http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#syncdb) it says

'South overrides the Django syncdb command; as well as changing the output to show apps delineated by their migration status, it also makes syncdb only work on a subset of the apps - those without migrations.'

but I don't fully understand it. If it overrides the Django syncdb command, then what would be the best way for me to sync

```
django.contrib.admin
```

and

```
django.contrib.flatpages
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly convert any of your `INSTALLED_APPS` to use South.

After installing South you can still do `python manage.py syncdb` to sync any apps that aren't using South (such as Flatpages)

To convert an app:
http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html

Comment: Ah okay so what I would do is first 'python manage.py syncdb' and then 'python manage.py convert_to_south django.contrib.followed by 'python manage.py convert_to_south django.contrib.flatpages'?

Comment: yes, except I wouldn't usually convert the `django.contrib` apps to South... you'd typically use it on your own apps where you are changing the schema as development progresses